# Variable Corruption in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Given the following code I am expecting the variable $NewFile to be /var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt.pdf

However my system is returning: ".pdf/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt"

$Ext returns: "txt"
$oFileName returns: "/var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt"

I have tried this a hundred different ways with no luck.

```
PDF=".pdf"

#extract the file.ext from the script
FileName1=`head $f -n1 | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\"//'`
FileName2=`head $f -n1 | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\"//'`
FileName3=`head $f -n1 | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\"//'`

FileName=`basename $FileName1`
Ext=`echo $FileName | awk -F . '{print $NF}'`

FileName=`basename $FileName2`
oFileName=/var/ftp/pub/faxes/${FileName}

FileName=`basename $FileName3`
NewFile=/var/ftp/pub/faxes/${FileName}${PDF}

echo $oFileName
echo $NewFile
echo $Ext
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you didn't echo `$FileName` or `$FileName3`, we can't help.

Comment: so it's actually replacing /var with .pdf? or is it supposed to be .pdf/var/ftp..?

Comment: You should add double quotes (`""`) around all assignments without backticks, so that filenames with spaces are handled correctly.

Comment: @Thomas, I have tried it with and without quotes, doesn't matter, the variable is returning corrupted as you see it above.

Comment: @roe, anything placed behind ${FileName} is being put in the front of the new variable, it is supposed to return /var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt.pdf

Comment: @S.Lott, $FileName returns as /var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt

Comment: @ec: I really can't reproduce that on my machine.  ".pdf" is appended at the end at it should.

Comment: @ec: show us the output of 'bash -x yourscript'.

Answer (score 4):

Comment: if you ever move to a normal Unix-like system instead of Linux, you won't get away with '`head $f -n1`'; you must put option (control) arguments before file names, so use '`head -n1 $f`'.  (If you set environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT, Linux will behave the same as other systems.)

Comment: you could perfectly well write:

```
FileName1=`head -n1 $f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\"//'`
FileName2=$Filename1
FileName3=$Filename1
```

It makes more sense than running the same three programs on the same data three times.

Comment: you should learn and use the '$(...)' notation:

```
FileName1=$(head -n1 $f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\"//')
```

When run on MacOS X, with f=xxxx.input and the file xxxx.input containing one line that says '/some/where/myfile.txt', the script produces:

```
/var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt
/var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt.pdf
txt
```

The trace output ('bash -x') is:

```
+ f=xxxx.input
+ PDF=.pdf
++ head -n 1 xxxx.input
++ sed 's/\"//'
++ awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
+ FileName1=myfile.txt
++ head -n 1 xxxx.input
++ awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
++ sed 's/\"//'
+ FileName2=myfile.txt
++ awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
++ head -n 1 xxxx.input
++ sed 's/\"//'
+ FileName3=myfile.txt
++ basename myfile.txt
+ FileName=myfile.txt
++ echo myfile.txt
++ awk -F . '{print $NF}'
+ Ext=txt
++ basename myfile.txt
+ FileName=myfile.txt
+ oFileName=/var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt
++ basename myfile.txt
+ FileName=myfile.txt
+ NewFile=/var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt.pdf
+ echo /var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt
/var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt
+ echo /var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt.pdf
/var/ftp/pub/faxes/myfile.txt.pdf
+ echo txt
txt
```

You will need to show what you're really using, and 'bash -x' may well help you see where your problem is -- I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the reply. what other info can I get you to help out here?

Comment: + PDF=.pdf
+ FileName1=$'faxtest.txt\r'
+ FileName2=$'faxtest.txt\r'
+ FileName3=$'faxtest.txt\r'
++ basename $'faxtest.txt\r'
+ FileName=$'faxtest.txt\r'
++ echo $'faxtest.txt\r'
++ awk -F . '{print $NF}'
+ Ext=$'txt\r'
++ basename $'faxtest.txt\r'
+ FileName=$'faxtest.txt\r'
+ oFileName=$'/var/ftp/pub/faxes/faxtest.txt\r'
++ basename $'faxtest.txt\r'
+ FileName=$'faxtest.txt\r'
+ NewFile=$'/var/ftp/pub/faxes/faxtest.txt\r.pdf'
+ echo $'/var/ftp/pub/faxes/faxtest.txt\r'
/var/ftp/pub/faxes/faxtest.txt
+ echo $'/var/ftp/pub/faxes/faxtest.txt\r.pdf'
.pdf/ftp/pub/faxes/faxtest.txt

Comment: I think I see my problem, the variable $FileName is being populated with a \r character.

Comment: If you imported the file from Windows (most plausible source of carriage returns at the ends of lines), then you should convert to Unix LF only line endings before processing further.  One way to do that is via the dos2unix or dtou commands; another way uses vim to edit the file, use ':set fileformat=unix' to change from DOS to Unix formats, and save the file again.

Comment: And you see the '.pdf' at the start because the embedded carriage return moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line after echoing the name, and then emits the '.pdf' over the beginning.